# How can I use jquery UI to create image tooltips on top of select options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a select box

```
<select name="template" id="id_template">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>
  <option value="1">twobytwo</option>
  <option value="6">twovert</option>
  <option value="7">twohoriz</option>
</select>
```

And I have images for each select

`/static/img/twobytwo.png`

`/static/img/twovert.png`

`/static/img/twohoriz.png`

How can I create a tooltip so that when a user hovers over an option, it displays the image associated with the option? All I've found is this which is close but not quite there http://jsfiddle.net/ndrDc/151/

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at the jQueryUI tooltip section? http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I just found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set a "size" attribute on the select div, and then:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items:"select#id_of_your_select,option",
        content : function(){
                return '<img src="my_image.png" width="50px"/>'
        },
    });
});
```